# Micronaut fail to connect to Keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, micronaut, amazon-keyspaces

I'm trying to integrate my service with AWS Cassandra (`Keyspaces`) with the following config:

```yaml
    cassandra:
      default:
        advanced:
          ssl: true
          ssl-engine-factory: DefaultSslEngineFactory
          metadata:
            schema:
              enabled: false
          auth-provider:
            class: PlainTextAuthProvider
            username: "XXXXXX"
            password: "XXXXXX"
        basic:
          contact-points:
            - ${CASSANDRA_HOST:"127.0.0.1"}:${CASSANDRA_PORT:"9042"}
          load-balancing-policy:
            local-datacenter: "${CASSANDRA_DATA_CENTER}:datacenter1"
          session-keyspace: "keyspace"
```

Whenever I'm running the service it fails to load with the following error:

```
Message: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=cassandra.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.248.244.41:9142, hostId=null, hashCode=7296b27b): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: [s0|control|id: 0x1f1c50a1, L:/172.17.0.3:54802 - R:cassandra.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.248.244.41:9142] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): timed out after 5000 ms]
```

There's very little documentation about the `cassandra-micronaut` library, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**UPDATE:**

For clarity: the values of our environment variables are as follow:

```sh
   export CASSANDRA_HOST=cassandra.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
   export CASSANDRA_PORT=9142
   export CASSANDRA_DATA_CENTER=eu-west-1
```

Note that even when I've hard-coded the values into my `application.yml` the problem continued.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to adjust your variables in this example.  The common syntax for Apache Cassandra or Amazon Keyspaces is `host:port`. For Amazon Keyspaces the port is always 9142.

Try the following:

```
contact-points:
 - ${CASSANDRA_HOST}:${CASSANDRA_PORT}
```

or simply hard code them at first.

```
contact-points:
 - cassandra.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:9142
```

Answer (score 0):

So this:

```
contact-points:
    - ${CASSANDRA_HOST:"127.0.0.1"}:${CASSANDRA_PORT:"9042"}
```

Doesn't match up with this:

```
Node(endPoint=cassandra.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.248.244.41:9142,
```

Double-check which IP(s) and port Cassandra is broadcasting on (usually seen with `nodetool status`) and adjust the service to not look for it on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Hi @Aaron , as I'm using Keyspaces and not managing my own cluster I don't have access to `nodetool status` (as far as I know).
I've updated the question with a bit more details